# Best Relationship Type When Organization is Primary Member

Tags: civimember

What relationship is best to use in a scenario where an individual signs up on behalf of an organization but the organization is actually the Member? Is it the Employer of or Employee of relationship type?

I want the Organization to be the primary Member.

Answer (score 3):

If the Organization is the Member, then you need the Membership Type to be set to use the "Employer of" relationship. If you go [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/member/membershipType/add?action=add&reset=1) and click on the '?' next to Relationship Type it says

Relationship Type: Employer of

Direct member is:   an organisation

Membership is automatically granted to: 'Employees' of that organization

Comment: Thanks a lot. That has confused me a litte until now. My next question relating to that is howdo i display organizations Dashboard when the Employee logs in because i would rather have the Organizations dashboard displayed.

Comment: CMS? If drupal then we aren't restricted to answers on the civi side of the equation ;-)

Comment: The CMS is Wordpress. Civicrm is 4.6.8

Comment: Suggest you ask that question as a separate question and explain a bit more perhaps with an example on the WP demo site. I have no idea with WP how you would have someone login, whose own dashboard is at civicrm/user?reset=1 and then grab their permissioned employer id and take them to eg civicrm/user?reset=1&id=208.